# Unity2D Jump doesn't work for unknown reasons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am going back into game devloppment after a few months and, while I was making a respawn trigger (that doesn't work), my jump stopped working for no reasons. I didn't modified the code (I think). I followed a tutorial for the code. Please not that I am using the unity *new* input system and that my game is a **2D GAME** Also, there is no errors shown in the logs, the problem is that when I press my jump key, it does nothing. I tried putting `Debug.Log("Should Jump");` in the jump code to see if the *Rigidbody2D* was the problem but it still didn't worked (nothing showed up in the logs). I also verified that my floor was in the *Ground* layer and it was. I don't see the problem.

My code is the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed;
    [SerializeField] Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundLayer;

    bool facingRight = true;
    PlayerInput playerInput;

    bool isGrounded;
    float groundTimer = 1f;
    float airTimer;

    void Start()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
        isGround();
    }

    void isGround()
    {
        if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.05f, groundLayer) && airTimer <- 0)
        {
            groundTimer = 0.15f;
            isGrounded = true;
        }

        if (airTimer > 0)
        {
            airTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            if (groundTimer < 0)
                isGrounded = false;
            else
                groundTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        transform.Translate(Mathf.Abs(playerInput.actions["Horizontal"].ReadValue<float>()) * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        //if (playerInput.actions["Jump"].triggered)
        
        if (playerInput.actions["Jump"].triggered && isGrounded && airTimer <- 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Debug.Log("Should Jump");
            isGrounded = false;
            airTimer = 0.06f;
        }

        //Just flipping
    }

    //More flipping
}
```

*Help...*

*(It's late for me so, if you ask a question, I will probably not anwser (22:52 EST 19 June 2022))*

Comment: If you are not seeing your debug statement when you press jump, then your if condition must always be false. You can add debug statements before your if statement to check each condition independently. One (or many) must always be false - from there you can debug further.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to figure out what part is missing